# Reading XML Elements and connect them in 1 variable

Tags: c#, .net, xml, string, unity-game-engine

I have an XML file which looks like this:

```
<instance>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <start>213.5000000000</start>
    <end>231.3900001049</end>
    <code>Away Pass</code>
    <label>
        <group>Pass</group>
        <text>SuccessfullyCompleted</text>
    </label>
    <label>
        <group>PassDistance</group>
        <text>Medium</text>
    </label>
    <label>
        <group>Player</group>
        <text>John Doe</text>
    </label>
</instance>
<instance>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <start>214.0000000000</start>
    <end>225.0000000000</end>
    <code>Kickoff</code>
    <label>
        <text>Pass</text>
    </label>
</instance>
<instance>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <start>215.0000000000</start>
    <end>226.0000000000</end>
    <code>ShotOnGoal</code>
</instance>
```

So each instance can contain none, one or several labels and each label does contain a text and some labels contain a text AND a group.

So my problem is: I want to get those values in one string for each instance. Each text should be separated by a comma and each group should be together with the text it belong to by a "=". So for example for the first istance the string should look like

> "Pass = SuccessfullyCompleted, PassDistance = Medium, Player = John Doe"

I really don't know how to implement this, therefore my code looks like this at the moment where I read groups and texts separated from each other:

```
var labelsGroupsTmp = from label in instance.Elements("label") select label.Element("group").Value;
string labelsGroups = string.Join(",", labelsGroupsTmp.ToArray());
var labelsTextTmp = from label in instance.Elements("label") select label.Element("text").Value;
string labelsText = string.Join(",", labelsTextTmp.ToArray());
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Instance with Id=3 doesn't have a group element, what is the result supposed to look like for that particular case?

Comment: Also, what about the 3rd instance? There's no labels, so should that particular instance be ignored?

Comment: @RuiJarimba If there is no group like in instance 2 (ID=3) than I just want to have the text.
If there is no label at all like in instance 3 (ID=4) than it should be empty/ignored

Comment: fixed my answer, according to your feedback. Which .NET version are you using BTW?

Comment: @RuiJarimba I'm not quite sure because I'm using it in unity (version 2018.2.2f1). I don't know where I can figure out which version of .NET is used there but I think it should be version 3.5

Comment: that's quite an old version of .NET, I probably need to add a new answer or edit my answer

Comment: I edited my answer. Most of the code was already compatible with .NET v3.5, except for 2 classes. Please let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you the text for an instance the way you want it. xml is the string containing the given XML, but you have to enclose it in a surrounding tag with an arbitrary Name, <s> in the code below, to be valid, as your sample contains multiple root elements.

```
var str = XElement.Parse(@"<s>
  <instance>...</instance>
  <instance>...</instance>
  <instance>...</instance>
</s>");
var emptyGroup = new XElement("group");
foreach (var instance in str.Elements("instance"))
{
  var labels = from label in instance.Elements("label")
    select string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
      label.Element("group") == null ? "" : label.Element("group").Value, 
      string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((label.Element("group") ?? emptyGroup).Value) ? "" : "=",
      label.Element("text").Value);
  string s = string.Join(", ", labels);
  // do whatever s is needed for
}
```

Comment: You need to declare the variable instance, otherwise your code sample won't even compile.

Comment: I tried to run your code but got an exception: `System.Xml.XmlException: 'There are multiple root elements. Line 19, position 2.'`

Comment: Your code worked for me.Thanks. The only thing was that I had to use "IsNullOrEmpty" instead of "IsNullOrWhiteSpace" because I'm running it in Unity and it said there is no definition for IsNullOrWhiteSpace.

Comment: IsNullOrWhiteSpace was introduced in .Net 4 I believe, maybe you are using an older version of the framework.

Comment: @RuiJarimba, the given xml must be enclosed in another arbitrary tag, as stated in my answer. Got the same error as you before.

Comment: @StefanIllner sorry I missed that for some reason. But IMO your should include that piece of code in your answer ;)

Comment: @RuiJarimba I added that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want! I think you can use a code like this:

```
var txt = $"<root>{text}</root>";
var xml = XDocument.Parse(txt);
var elems = xml.XPathSelectElements("//instance").Select(
    x =>
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var le in x.Elements("label"))
            {
                sb.Append(", ");
                sb.Append(le.Element("group") == null ? string.Empty : le.Element("group")?.Value + "=");
                sb.Append(le.Element("text") == null ? string.Empty : le.Element("text")?.Value);
            }

            if (sb.Length > 0)
            {
                sb.Remove(0, 2);
            }

            return new { Instance = x, LabelString = sb.ToString() };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution - I decided to create a `Label` class to map 1 single label and a `LabelGroup` class to map all the labels of a specific `<instance>` element:

```
public class Label
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Group))
        {
            return Text ?? string.Empty;
        }

        return $"{Group ?? string.Empty} = {Text ?? string.Empty}";
    }
}

public class LabelGroup
{
    private readonly List<Label> _labels;

    public LabelGroup(List<Label> labels)
    {
        _labels = labels ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(labels));
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (_labels.Any())
        {
            return string.Join(", ", _labels);
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And then use some Linq to get the data:

```
string xml = "...."; // xml goes here

var groups = from instance in XDocument.Parse($"<root>{xml}</root>").Descendants("instance")
             let labels = instance.Descendants("label")
             where labels.Any() // ignore <instance> without <label> elements
             let labelList = CreateLabels(labels)
             select new LabelGroup(labelList);


foreach (var labelGroup in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(labelGroup);
}
```

CreateLabels method:

```
private static List<Label> CreateLabels(IEnumerable<XElement> elements)
{
    List<Label> labels = elements.Select(x => new Label {
        Group = x.Element("group")?.Value,
        Text = x.Element("text")?.Value
    }).ToList();

    return labels;
}
```

Please note that you need to wrap your XML in a dummy element to avoid the error `System.Xml.XmlException: 'There are multiple root elements. Line 19, position 2.'` as follows:

```
XDocument.Parse($"<root>{xml}</root>")
```

## EDIT

Given that the OP is using an older version of the .NET Framework (3.5), classes `Label` and `LabelGroup` should be changed as follows. The rest of the code should be compatible with .NET 3.5:

```
public class Label
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Group))
        {
            return Text;
        }

        return string.Format("{0} = {1}", Group ?? string.Empty, Text ?? string.Empty);
    }
}

public class LabelGroup
{
    private readonly List<Label> _labels;

    public LabelGroup(List<Label> labels)
    {
        if (labels == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("labels");
        }

        _labels = labels;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (_labels.Any())
        {
            return string.Join(", ", _labels.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```